# Doctrine2 findBy() order by joined table field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony2 with Doctrine2. There are the following entities:

```
/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\Bundle\ConsysBundle\Entity\PersonRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="persons", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $company;

}
```

and

```
/**
 * Company
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\Bundle\ConsysBundle\Entity\CompanyRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

Now in my controller I need to do the following:

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeConsysBundle:Person');
    $people = $repository->findBy(
            array(),
            // here I want to order by the company name
            // that is taken from the Company entity
            array('company.name' => 'asc') 
    );
```

This code of course doesn't work, saying that "company.name" is unrecognized. But then how can I order by that column? Is it possible to do using findBy()?

Comment: I think it's not possible with findby, but you can make a customquery

Comment: please review my answer and comment if anything unclear - otherwise pleae accept it :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

add this to your PersonRepository

```
public function findAllOrderByCompany()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.company','c')
        ->orderBy('c.name', 'asc')
        ->getQuery() 
        ->getResult();
}
```

If you want to sort an exisiting collection of Person entities by Company::getName

```
$iterator = $collection->getIterator();
$iterator->uasort(function ($a, $b) {
    return ($a->getCompany()->getName() < $b->getCompany()->getName()) ? -1 : 1;
});
$collection = new ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($iterator));
```

Comment: Ok, I've just checked the sources and, you are right, I will need to use query builder.

The second option is not really a solution for me, because it will be overhead on big data amounts.

Comment: just included it to let people know its possible to re-sort their collections this way :)

Comment: I accepted your code without testing. And however the idea is ok, but the implementation is not. createQueryBuilder() doesn't accept array as a parameter. Could you please fix your answer in order to not confuse people later?

Comment: thanks for the comment, hacked it down quickly - will update the answer  with a working querybuilder :)