# Doctrine2 - Annotation - "findOneBy" on column in "OneToOne" joined table

Tags: php, join, doctrine-orm, annotations

Using Doctrine2, I am trying to execute a `findOneBy` on an entity, where I have a joined a table using `OneToOne`, and I want to search for columns in the joined table.

The two PHP entities in play are (in simplified versions):

**Page**:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Page")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Page extends EntityInterface
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
   */
  public $isActive;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\PageLocalization")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="pageId")
   * })
   **/
  public $pageLocalization;
}
```

**PageLocalization**:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="PageLocalization")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class PageLocalization extends EntityInterface
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
  public $pageId;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string")
   */
  public $localeCode;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string")
   */
  public $title;
}
```

The entities work and I can extract data just fine through e.g. `$entityRepository->findOneBy(["id"=>1])`.

Now, for instance, I want to search for `Page.id = 1`, `Page.isActive = true` and `PageLocalization.localeCode = "en-US"`. How is this search performed?

My attempt below doesn't work.

```
$entityRepository->findOneBy([
  "id" => 1,
  "isActive" => true,
  "pageLocalization" => [
    "localeCode" => "en-US"
  ]
]);
```

I had no luck finding the answer through Google, Stackoverflow, or the Doctrine2 documentation.

The most frequent solutions I see is that people settle for are constructing the queries manually using `$entityManager->createQueryBuilder()`. However, I feel this approach defies the purpose of having the entities.

Is this type of search possible at all using purely annotations and entities?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered thus far, it is indeed **not** possible to perform a search like this across multiple entities (joined tables) using any of the [`EntityRepository`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html)'s "find" methods; `find`, `findAll`, `findBy`, and `findOneBy`.

Stackoverflow answers to similar questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16730168/1879194
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12258270/1879194
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19489147/1879194

The list goes on...

**Conclusion**

One must perform this type of searches using [DQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) or the [`QueryBuilder`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html).

**Thoughts**

I find this limitation to be highly obnoxious and a serious feature inadequacy in Doctrine2.

If half the time, when I want to touch the database, I have to build the queries myself, why would I bother adhering to and maintaining two drastically different approaches; (1) an ORM with entities reflecting database tables and (2) constructing pure SQL requests through a DBAL, e.g. PDO or Doctrine's DQL?

**Doctrine2 considerations (slightly off-topic)**

I really want to learn how to work with and utilize Doctrine2 efficiently. And while Doctrine2 does have a grand array of nice features, it certainly also consists of some massive rebar walls, which one keeps running into face-first. Google and Stackoverflow certainly has a bunch of "Why can't I ...?" questions related to Doctrine2 and joining tables in particular.